# Python function that returns a value a certain percent of the time

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, sample

During an interview, I was given the following coding question that I couldn't figure out. I've been thinking about it ever since then, and I can't seem to figure out how to write a function that returns a value for a given percent of the time.

The question goes as follows:

> > Say you have a dictionary dict = {'A': 10, 'B': 30, 'C': 60}. Write a function that returns 'A' 10% of the time, 'B' 30% of the time, and 'C' 60% of the time. So, the function should take in a dictionary with values as numbers (they don't necessarily have to add up to 100), and it should return that value's key in correspondence with the percentage that key is to the sum of all the keys.

I have an idea of how to start the function...

```
def percent_return(dict):
    sum = 0
    for key, value in dict.items():
        sum += float(value)
    percent_array = []
    for key, value in dict.items():
        percent = float(value) / sum
        percent_array.append(percent)
 ''' We now have an array with the associated percentages for the dictionary, 
but now I don't know how to actually apply this to the return values '''
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if (something that indicates given %):
            return key
```

I'm very new to python, so please excuse my ignorance and thanks for your help!

Comment: The first mistake is using `sum` and `dict` as variable names. Don't shadow built-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `random.randrange` to draw a value between 0 and the sum of all dict values, use `itertools.accumulate` to generate a sequence of cumulative sums from the values, and then use `itertools.dropwhile` to look for the first cumulative sum that isn't less than the draw, and return the key of the dict at that index, as accompanied by the cumulative sum through the use of `enumerate`:

```
import random
from itertools import accumulate, dropwhile
def pick(d):
    draw = random.randrange(sum(d.values()))
    return list(d.keys())[next(dropwhile(lambda t: t[1] < draw, enumerate(accumulate(d.values()))))[0]]
```

so that:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'A': 10, 'B': 30, 'C': 60}
print(Counter(pick(d) for _ in range(1000)))
```

can output:

```
Counter({'C': 587, 'B': 286, 'A': 127})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You shadow `sum` and `dict` built-ins. Never do this.
2. You correctly calculate an array of percentages but haven't linked them to keys.
3. There is no logic to retrieve a weighted sample from your keys.

The built-in `random.choice` already has this functionality. For efficiency, you can use `sum` with `dict.values` directly and use a dictionary comprehension to calculate weights. Since `random.choices` returns a list, we can use `next` with `iter` to extract the only element.

```
from random import choices

d_weights = {'A': 10, 'B': 30, 'C': 60}

def percent_return(d):
    val_sum = sum(d.values())
    d_pct = {k: v/val_sum for k, v in d.items()}
    return next(iter(choices(population=list(d_pct), weights=d_pct.values(), k=1)))

res = percent_return(d_weights)
```

Comment: I don't understand why next is needed. why isn't just choices enough?

Comment: @jgcello, `choices` returns a list, in this case a list with one element. To get a scalar, you can either use `choices(...)[0]` or `next(iter(choices(...))`. The latter is actually more in line with the thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be it? ... I'm not sure I understood the question, though my code will print out each Key depending on their "chance".

```python
from random import randint

example = {
    'A': 10,
    'B': 50,
    'C': 80
}

def percent_return(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if randint(1, 100) < value:
            yield key

for char in percent_return(example):
    print(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choices* accepts weighted distribution, not sure if goal is to print or store in count but either can be done this way

```
from random import choices
d = {'A': 10, 'B': 30, 'C': 60}
l = []
for i in range(sum([v for v in d.values()])):
    l.append(*choices([k for k in d],[.1, .3, .6]))

print(l)
print({i: l.count(i) for i in [k for k in d]})
```

> ```
> ['C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',..., 'C', 'C', 'B']
> {'A': 8, 'B': 30, 'C': 62}
> ```